# Why would reading a passphrase from STDIN be disallowed but not from a PTY or argument?

Tags: shell-script, terminal, security

I have [a program](https://vaultproject.io) that receives a secret passphrase. The options I have are to type it in manually on the terminal or to provide it as a command line argument. This makes it hard to automate in a secure way: typically there is no terminal when the script will be run, and I don't want to pass the passphrase on the command line as it will be readable via `ps` and the like.

For example (on a terminal):

```
$ vault operator unseal
Unseal Key (will be hidden):
```

(it works)

```
$ vault operator unseal <<<"$PASSPHRASE"
Unseal Key (will be hidden): 
An error occurred attempting to ask for an unseal key. The raw error message
is shown below, but usually this is because you attempted to pipe a value
into the unseal command or you are executing outside of a terminal (tty). You
should run the unseal command from a terminal for maximum security. If this
is not an option, the unseal key can be provided as the first argument to the
unseal command. The raw error was:  file descriptor 0 is not a terminal
```

(it does not work)

I have managed to overcome this with

```
socat STDIO 'EXEC:vault operator unseal,PTY' <<<"$PASSPHRASE"
```

but is this a bad idea? This seems like the safest way to pass in the passphrase, though surly the creators of `vault` had their reasons for not accepting the passphrase on STDIN and I want to be sure I'm not doing something insecure.

Comment: `vault operator unseal -` treats `-` as a passphrase. It doesn't read from stdin

Comment: I guess the creators of vault subscribe to the idea that a passphrase should be entered by a human, not a program. Storing a sensitive passphrase in a file just for the purpose of feeding it into another program is "security by obscurity", not real security. By trying to enforce that the passphrase is read from a terminal they are trying to ensure a human is typing it. Unfortunately, as you have shown, this can be circumvented. Accepting the passphrase via standard input would also make life easier for authors of malware, should the passphrase leak.

Comment: If all the programs accepted passwords from stdin (or from environment, the arg list is still a no because it's visible to anyone), then where would be the market for things like `sshpass`? Who would still struggle while cluelessly copy-pasting tcl into an `expect` script? FWIW, if that `vault` program would've used the libc's `getpass(3)` function instead of rolling their own thing, it would've need something more elaborate to make it work ;-)

Comment: I tried the socat trick with a recent version, Vault v1.14.4. Did not work. The secret seems to be entered into the input stream before the prompt for the secret happens. Result is an unsuccessful unseal.
I would like to use this solution instead of passing the secret as cli argument, because I want to minimise the risk that the secret could be sniffed via ps. At least, I believe that this risk exists.
For me an alternative would be if vault would implement the usage of an environment variable to pass this secret.